# Server 2012 DC in VMWare virtual network (NAT) unable to connect to the internet

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, vmware-workstation

I am trying to set up a virtual lab on my laptop in an attempt to get into some SharePoint development. As a developer, my knowledge of Windows Server and VMWare is limited so I'm following the blog posts from [Randy Rempel](http://bit.ly/14Oh0rY).

I configured the environment ([part 1](http://bit.ly/1bLohPd)), installed and configured the domain controller ([part 2](http://bit.ly/1ajho9O)) and started the installation of SQL Server 2012 ([part 3](http://bit.ly/1eWe4PN)). The linked blog posts contain screenshots and my setup looks identical.

After installing the second virtual machine to host SQL Server 2012 I was able to log in on the machine using a domain account created on the domain controller. The two virtual machines are able to connect to each other and I was quite pleased with my personal success. :-)

Unfortunately, after continuing I bumped into an issue. Neither the DC or the SQL Server guest have access to the internet. And I don't know where I went wrong. In theory this wouldn't be a problem, but I noticed that during the install of SQL Server 2012 an attempt is made to contact Windows Update and that failed. So I went looking and found that I cannot connect to the internet. The network icon on both servers has a yellow icon and shows up as limited.

So, the question is: why? Following the steps on the blog posts, where did I go wrong or which VMWare setting might have I forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is ping 8.8.8.8 and tracert google.com output?

I suggest that you have installed dns role along with DC and didn't configure it properly.

Also check network settings (for example, from ipconfig /all )

Comment: I currently have no access to my laptop, but I will try to ping Google when I get home. I simply did not think of trying that.

Comment: The ping command works, the tracert command reports it cannot resolve the target system. As per the screenshots in the blog post, the DNS settings on my DC's network connection are empty.

Comment: So, I did a re-install. After the re-install I assigned my Gateway as the Primary DNS and got internet. After installing the DNS roles the Primary DNS was set to 127.0.0.1 and I lost internet access.

Comment: Ok, it's really dns problem. Go to dns-server snap-in and configure there dns forwarders for your server

Comment: After looking up how DNS forwarders work and adding them this indeed solved the issue. I'm therefore accepting your answer.